# MySQL query with less than or greater than in the where statement using aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an MySQL query that is super simple but having an issue and wondering if someone can shed some light. All I am trying to do is include two aggregative functions that add "this year"+"last_year" at the same time filter out any results with less than 200 total_votes

Currently, the query works and the output looks like this:

```
name   | total_votes
--------------------
apple  |    119
lemon  |    218
orange |    201
pear   |    111
```

---

However when I add a where statement I get a syntax error:

```
 select 
        name,
        sum(this_year)+sum(last_year) as total_votes
        from fruit_sales
        group by name
        where total_votes>200
```

The above results in this syntax error in my SQL fiddle:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where total>200' at line 6"
```

I've also tried:

```
select 
name,
sum(this_year)+sum(last_year)>200 as total_votes
from fruit_sales
group by name
```

Here is an SQLfiddle with the table and my query in the works:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6862/11

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6862/14 WHERE filters pre aggregation HAVING filters post aggregation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(this_year)+SUM(last_year) as total_votes
 FROM fruit_sales
 GROUP BY name
 HAVING SUM(this_year)+SUM(last_year) > 200
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6862/15/0)**</kbd>

You can also calculate sum as:

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(this_year + last_year) as total_votes
FROM fruit_sales
GROUP BY name
HAVING total_votes > 200;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6862/18/0)**</kbd>

For `@lcm` without `HAVING` and using subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(this_year + last_year) as total_votes
 FROM fruit_sales
 GROUP BY name) AS sub
WHERE total_votes > 200;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo3`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6862/20/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Why do the calculations again?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using HAVING?

Comment: If you want to do it in a where without using a having do the calculations again.. Having can reference the table alias so there's no need to do it there

Comment: @JohnRuddell Why do the calculation again? I am from SQL Server world. There you cannot use alias in HAVING so I just in my natural way. Probably in MySQL it behaves differently, and will calculate it again(if so then query optimizer in MySQL is really weak). Anyway thanks for downvote.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the feldname from the select

```
select 
name,
sum(this_year)+sum(last_year) as total_votes
from fruit_sales

group by name
having total_votes>200;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first query, you have two values you are trying to reference: `total_votes` and `total`. Make sure that you are referencing the correct value for the query to work

Comment: Cannot reference an alias in a where

Comment: Thanks @JohnRuddell !

Comment: Thanks for the note on my mistake...I made the edit to change total to total_votes.

Comment: That didn't fix it.. The op was trying to say where total_votes >200 which is invalid since total_votes can't be called in the where